# Lodash isEqualWith with customizer not checking fields

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to do an equality comparison ignoring undefined values using lodash.

I'd expect the following to work:

```
console.log(
  isEqualWith(request.body, actualRequest.body.json, (a, b) => {
    console.log(a, b, a === undefined && b === undefined ? true : undefined
    );
    return a === undefined && b === undefined ? true : undefined;
  })
);
```

However, the console output fails on the 'first' comparison (of the whole objects), even though the customizer returns undefined. Here's the output:

```
{ item1: undefined, item2: 'test'} { item2: 'test' } undefined
false
```

It's never comparing anything except the first object. I'd expect an output like:

```
{ item1: undefined, item2: 'test'} { item2: 'test' } undefined
undefined undefined true
'test' 'test' undefined
true
```

As, given the customizer returned undefined for the first check, then it would have gone through the fields of the object and performed the customzer check on those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you return `undefined` in the case of object, the method `_.isEqualWith()` makes many comparison to decide if the objects are equal or not. It actually checks if the [number of keys](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/equalObjects.js#L29) is the same in both objects, which fails in your case. If it had the same number of keys, it would fail when making `hasOwnProperty` checks.

To make a partial comparison that ignores `undefined` values, use [`_.isMatch()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isMatch), which actually uses the same logic but ignores the `length` (and other checks) by setting the `bitmask` for `COMPARE_PARTIAL_FLAG`.

```js
const o1 = { item1: undefined, item2: 'test' } 
const o2 = { item2: 'test' }

const result = _.isMatch(o1, o2)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it compares things like the number of keys. I think I've actually used isMatch in the past too, should have thought of it!

Comment: Ah, a problem with isMatch is does a wholly partial check (i.e. `{a: 1}` is a match with `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`, not just `{ a: 1, b: undefined }`.

Comment: Indeed. Your question was presented has have { key: value, key: undefined }.

Comment: Yes, certainly answered my question! And identified the problem. I can find a solution now I know the reason it wasn't working is due to `isEqual` doing a field count comparison! (thinking an `omitBy` with an undefined check) Not complaining!

Comment: Wasn't thinking you were. Just wanted to know, if the problem changed :) It seems that you need to create a custom isEqual.